# Page Not Found with Akka-http

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have a scala project that uses akka-http.  I've created a CRUD based on this project:
https://github.com/ajtechdeveloper/BasicAkkaHTTP/tree/e746a534a8ca33ff27d54a87c888501a8aac6653

I have a router that looks like this:

```
trait ImageResource extends MyResource {



val imageService: ImageService

  def imageRoutes: Route = pathPrefix("image") {
    pathEnd {
      post {
        entity(as[Image]) { image =>
          completeWithLocationHeader(
            resourceId = imageService.createImage(image),
            ifDefinedStatus = 201, ifEmptyStatus = 409)
        }
      }
    } ~
      path(Segment) { id =>
        get {
          complete(imageService.getImage(id))
        } ~
          put {
            entity(as[ImageUpdate]) { update =>
              complete(imageService.updateImage(id, update))
            }
          } ~
          delete {
            complete(imageService.deleteImage(id))
          }
      }
    }

}
```

However, I want to be able to handle what happens when the user goes to a route that does not exist.  I have no idea where to even start, and everything I've tried has failed!  Grateful for any advice!

Comment: RejectionHandlers is what you need: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/rejections.html#customizing-rejection-handling

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed, thank you!